# Automapper Intellisense not working in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, automapper, intellisense

I have VS2010, 12, 13, 15 on my machine. All versions except 15 (Enterprise) work with Intellisense for Automapper.

Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<B, C>()
            .ForMember(x => x.)    // this is where it breaks
    }
}

class B
{
    public string BB { get; set; }
}

class C
{
    public string CC { get; set; }
}
```

I have reproduced this on two machines now by:

1. Creating a console project
2. Adding a reference from Nuget for Automapper `install-package automapper`
3. Writing the above code

In previous VS versions, as soon as I hit the `x => x.` I get Intellisense with destination members.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue. What I have observed is you need to provide the complete syntax for the intellisense to show up

Copy-paste the sample code below and replace with your source and destinations. Then remove the sample items ".ChildDetails", you will start seeing intellisense!

`Mapper.CreateMap<tblBusinessName, BusinessNameBO>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.ChildDetails, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.tblBusinessNameChild));`

Comment: This worked for me. And to clarify, I literally only had to type a comma for second parameter, go back and intellisense started listing the properties correctly.

Comment: Yes I also noticed this! Also I forgot to mention the versions - VS 2015, ASP.NET5/Core 1.0 and AutoMapper 4.1.1

Comment: Same thing here. AutMapper 5.0.2

Comment: Same thing here. AutMapper 6.0.2 on VS2013

Comment: @CraigFetherling, adding the comma should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Update AutoMapper in VS2015 or delete AutoMapper and install
2. In VS2015 check : Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All languages
   -> [Auto list members] and [Parameter Information]

what AutoMapper  version you have installed?

Comment: Thanks for the input. Options checked and had tried uninstalling/reinstalling AutoMapper. It's the latest AutoMapper on nuget, 4.1.1.

Comment: @Sam, i have version 3.2.1 and it works. I updated to 4.1.1 and it works with your code.